# FactoMineR PCA takes a really long time

Tags: r, pca

I'm trying to run a `PCA` on a really large dataset (160 000 x 20 000 variables, approx 6.3G in the file but much more when loaded in R) on a cluster. However, it is taking a high amount of time (my job was killed after 90 hours) while it was usually done in a few hours on datasets half the size.

I'm using the most basic R code possible :

```
data=read.table("dataset.csv", header=T, sep=',',row.names=1, fill=TRUE)
y=PCA(data, ncp=100, graph=FALSE)
```

Is there something wrong with what I'm doing or should I try a PCA from another package?

Comment: try ``irlba::prcomp_irlba()``

Comment: try reducing `ncp`